# MySQL Injection going wrong

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, sql-injection

I was testing security of a friend's site and I found SQL Injection vulnerability by putting `'` at end of URL
The site is built in zend framework
The issue I am having is the comment syntax in MySQL `--` is not working so the page is still throwing error

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by 1--) ORDER BY companies.company_name ASC' at line 8
in /home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 157
```

If you look up the error, the query is not terminated after `--`

Even `#` and `--+-`is not working

Comment: It may be that to end an SQL command requires a semicolon. If you did this: `'order by 1;--`

Comment: What was the actual code you were injecting?

Answer (score 1):

By putting ' at the end of the URL and the website is throwing out an error doesn't always mean it's vulnerable against SQLi.

Comment: But my question is why query is not terminated ? :(

Comment: Because it's been built badly? Without seeing the code that generates the query in question we can only speculate.